How can i deploy a zip file to an azure app service using az cli?
I have a zip file of my app ,  i want to do is deploy to an azure app service , im using
az webapp deploy   --resource-group <resource-group-name>   --name <web-app-name>   --package <path-to-zip-file>   --type zip

but it gives an error saying that my resource-group-name is not in the az webapp deploy command group , how is this so ?
How can i get this to work or is there a better way ?

does your resource-group-name contain any non-alphanumeric characters, like - or _ ?

The resourcegroup name is    Test-React-Client

You need to enclose the Resource-Group in quotes then.

do i need to put " Test-React-Client" ?

Try --resource-group "Test-React-Client"

I have still the same issue

What if you use cmd.exe instead of PowerShell?

az webapp deploy --resource-group "Test-React" --name "Test-React-Client" --src-path "c\temp\react.zip" --async true

that is what i have set

I prefer powershell if possible

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@Dai, there is no need to put Test-React-Client in quotes, and doing so can't be expected to make a difference. There is no shell-level syntax problem at play here, seemingly only an unsupported az webapp deploy parameter, --package.

To deploy a zip file to an app service using Az CLI, using
az webapp deploy works as you already did.
But there is no argument called --package available in deployment command. Instead, you need to use --src-path argument as shown in the below format.
az webapp deploy --resource-group Jahnavi --name appnet --src-path webapptodayupload.zip --type zip



Note: According to the error "resource-group-name is not in the az webapp deploy command group", make sure that the web app existed in the resource group you are giving. And also check the status of the resource group whether it is running properly. If still its not working, try deploying into a newly created resource group to avoid conflicts.
Alternatively, you can also use Publish-AzWebApp PowerShell command to deploy a zip file to an app service if still the issue persists with Azure CLI.
Refer MSDoc for the same PowerShell command execution.
